# Recursive Binary Search C++ without if-else statement

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, binary-search

I am trying to implement recursive binary search in C++. However my algorithm cannot find the last two elements from the test array.I know that I am missing something. I have searched a lot for such a implementation of binary search algorithm but without success. Can anyone help me with it?

```
 bool isMember (int x, int a[], int size){
    if (size == 0) return false;
    return a[size/2] == x ||
          (a[size/2] < x && isMember (x,a+size/2,(size)/2)) ||
          (a[size/2] > x && isMember (x,a,(size)/2));
}
```

Comment: How do you tell if it's your middle element without one if statement?

Comment: What does the `member` function do?

Comment: @MeetTitan a[size/2] represents the middle element in every recursive call. My fault I meant isMember.

Comment: "Middle element" is ill-defined if you have an even number of elements.

Comment: You have a problem when `size` is odd – for instance, when it is 3, you will divide into `a + 1` with size 1, and `a` with size 1. `a[2]` has gone missing.

Comment: Your problem is when you have an even number of members and try and split this into two subranges and a middle item. Your problem is when you split this into two subranges they are not always correct. Calculate the size of one sub-range. Then subtract that from the other total to get the size of the other sub range (don't forget to remove the middle item from the sub ranges.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No `if` statements here:

```
#include <iostream>

bool isMember (int x, int a[], int size)
{
    return size == 0 ? false
         : a[size/2] == x ? true
         : a[size/2] > x ? isMember(x, a, size/2)
         : isMember(x, a+size/2+1, size-(size/2+1));
}

int main()
{
    int v[]={1,2,4,8,16};

    for (int i=0; i<20; ++i)
        std::cout << i << ": " << isMember(i, v, 5) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0: 0
1: 1
2: 1
3: 0
4: 1
5: 0
6: 0
7: 0
8: 1
9: 0
10: 0
11: 0
12: 0
13: 0
14: 0
15: 0
16: 1
17: 0
18: 0
19: 0
```

Comment: haha no `if`, only ternary operator :D nice, nice, I like it.

Comment: Changing the parameters in the method from the question it works without the ternary operator as well.

Comment: You can't change the question. If you want to change the requirements, ask a new question (yes, it's easy to do it without the ternary operator also).

Comment: No, no I just explain to @Vucko that it works without ternary operator too. Thank you Sam.

Comment: @samVarshavchik I know bro, it just sheer joy I feel when I see an answer like this :D